# Orthographic Projection was automatically turned on when I used front/left/top view but now it doesnt work

Tags: interface

I factory reset my pc and reinstalled the blender. And my current situation is, before I factory reset, pressing <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, and <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> will automatically turn view perspective ortho on. But now they don't. I've been trying to fix this but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

By view perspective ortho I meant this [image]

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Have you checked the preference settings if the feature is turned on? Navigation (tab) > Orbit & Pan (1st section) > Auto [X] Perspective (checkbox in the middle). It must be checked

Answer (score 2):

As @Blunder commented, it's a setting in *User Preferences → Navigation:*
[image]